# Загрузка файлов на сайт PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Файл загружается через форму а в обработчике вот такой код - файл загружается и на сайт и в базу но ссылка не него косячит - тоесть он не вызывается скажите пожалуйста что не так

```
//преобразуем картинку для сообщения если она есть
if (empty($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']))
{
$uploadimg = ' ';//если переменной не существует 
}

else 
{
//иначе - загружаем изображение пользователя
$uploaddir='uploadimages/';//папка, куда будет загружаться начальная картинка и ее        сжатая копия

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"],    "$uploaddir".$_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]);
$uploadimg = '$uploaddir.$_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]';

}

$result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (author, poluchatel, date, text, imgfile) VALUES ('$author','$poluchatel','$date','$text','$uploadimg')",$db);//заносим в базу сообщение
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все надо было вот так подправить)
$uploadimg = $uploaddir.$_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"];

Answer (score 2):

Начать стоит с проверки того, что вам возвращает `move_uploaded_file`. Если по какой-то причине она не смогла закинуть файл в папку, она выдаст `false`.

Далее. Проверьте указанный путь на запись.

Типа того:

```
file_put_contents($uploaddir.'testfile.txt','test data');
```

Если запишет, начинаете проверять что же вам пришло в форме (вдруг не уложились в какие-то ограничения?).

Последнее, если все загружено ОК, то проверьте саму ссылку. Она может быть РАЗНАЯ для скрипта и для пользователя, так как они смотрят на файл из разных каталогов.

Comment: все ок косяк вот тут: 
    $uploadimg = '$uploaddir.$_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]';
при создании ссылки для БД(